# <VBA> shape Hyperlink does not work when timer api is running (powerpoint vba)

Tags: vba, api, timer, hyperlink, powerpoint

I am making a function to move a figure with a mouse using timer api, but the hyperlink of the moving shape does not work.

Comment: Not sure your question is a [reprex]. Can you [edit]  in more detail?

Comment: "Timer api" tells us nothing. Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

VBA is single threaded. This means that you can't have two code paths running at the same time.

If you have a timer event running then no other code can run until that is over.

This might be "an XY problem": http://xyproblem.info/

If you tell us what you are trying to do then we can help you get there. As it is, the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: I know the XY problem well. I didn't know it had a name.  Thanks for this. Nice one.